# Illegal Address Issue with Modbus Slave using j2mod

Tags: java, modbus, modbus-tcp

I am using J2mod library for my modbus communication needs. I basically want to create modbus slave using java service , which will be updated by another java service. To simulate this I am writing 2 test classes , however on reading from master, I keep getting illegal address issue. I am definitely missing something in slave creation since if I use tools like ModbusSlaveSlim it works fine.

ModbusSlaveApp

```
SimpleProcessImage spi = new SimpleProcessImage(1);
        spi.addRegister(47, new SimpleRegister(251));
        ModbusSlave slave = ModbusSlaveFactory.createTCPSlave(502, 5);
        slave.addProcessImage(1, spi);
        slave.open();
        ModbusTCPListener listener = new ModbusTCPListener(5, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), false);
        listener.setPort(502);
        listener.setListening(true);
        listener.setTimeout(5000);// 5 Seconds
```

ModbusMasterApp

```
ModbusTCPMaster tcpMaster = new ModbusTCPMaster("127.0.0.1", 502);
tcpMaster.connect();
// TEST READ FOR PUMP SETTINGS
Register[] data1 = tcpMaster.readMultipleRegisters(1, 47, 2);
```

I seem to have address correct but still keep getting Illegal Data Address exception

Comment: Do you get the same result when reading one register, i.e. `readMultipleRegisters(1, 47, 1)`?

Comment: yes even for single register had same issue